# Accessing results from a list column when some elements are NA

Tags: r, try-catch, tidyverse, purrr

## Problem: List column contains a few missing values

### Data

Consider the following tibble that contains the results of 2 model fits:

```
> Model_fits
# A tibble: 4 x 4
    cyl               data model1    model2   
  <dbl> <list<tibble[,2]>> <list>    <list>   
1     2            [5 x 2] <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>
2     4           [11 x 2] <lm>      <lm>     
3     6            [7 x 2] <lm>      <dbl [1]>
4     8           [14 x 2] <lm>      <lm>
```

The data for `cyl==2` was missing in this example. Therefore, `model1` contains `NA_real_` in the first row. Similarly, `model2` contains `NA_real_` in rows 1 and 3.

### Extracting model results

I want to extract the results of model fit using `broom::glance`. But it does not work due to the missing values:

```
> Model_fits %>% 
+   mutate(summary_res = map(model1, broom::glance))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `summary_res`.
x No glance method for objects of class numeric
i Input `summary_res` is `map(model1, broom::glance)`.
```

### Attempt at solution

So, I try to use `purrr::possibly`, but that does not work either:

```
> Model_fits %>% 
+   mutate(summary_res1 = map(model1, ~ possibly(broom::glance(.x),
+                                              otherwise = NA_real_)))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `summary_res1`.
x No glance method for objects of class numeric
i Input `summary_res1` is `map(model1, ~possibly(broom::glance(.x), otherwise = NA_real_))`.
```

### Expected outcome

I want to get the `broom::glance` results for all non-missing values and `NA_real_` for all missing values. Please guide me how can I get these results?

##### Code for creating `Model_fits`

Please note that I created the following as a reproducible example. But this is not my original data/model results.

```
library(tidyverse)

new_data <- tibble(mpg = rep(NA_real_, 5),
       cyl = rep(2, 5),
       disp = rep(NA_real_, 5))

mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(mpg, cyl, disp)

mt <- bind_rows(mtcars2, 
                new_data)
  
model_res_list <- map(mtcars2 %>% group_split(cyl), ~lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .x))

lizt <- list(NA_real_, model_res_list[[1]], model_res_list[[2]], model_res_list[[3]])

lizt2 <- list(NA_real_, model_res_list[[1]], NA_real_, model_res_list[[3]])


Model_fits <- mt %>% 
  group_nest(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(model1 = lizt,
         model2 = lizt2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more thing you could do about this is using `tryCatch` function, So that you define in case of an error occurring what would be the output of your function. In this case it will not bring the execution of the function to a halt.

```
Model_fits %>%
  mutate(mod01 = map(model1, ~ tryCatch(glance(.x), 
                                        error = function(cond) {
                                          NA_real_
                                        }))) %>%
  unnest(mod01)

# A tibble: 4 x 17
    cyl         data model1  model2 mod01 r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value    df
  <dbl> <list<tibbl> <list>  <list> <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     2      [5 x 2] <dbl [~ <dbl ~    NA   NA             NA     NA      NA      NA          NA
2     4     [11 x 2] <lm>    <lm>      NA    0.648          0.609  2.82   16.6     0.00278     1
3     6      [7 x 2] <lm>    <dbl ~    NA    0.0106        -0.187  1.58    0.0537  0.826       1
4     8     [14 x 2] <lm>    <lm>      NA    0.270          0.209  2.28    4.44    0.0568      1
# ... with 6 more variables: logLik <dbl>, AIC <dbl>, BIC <dbl>, deviance <dbl>,
#   df.residual <int>, nobs <int>
```

If we want to use `possibly` or `safely` instead of `tryCatch` we should first write a custom function that wraps `glance` in general and before applying on our data set:

```
poss_glance <- possibly(glance, otherwise = NA_real_)

Model_fits %>%
  mutate(mod01 = map(model1, ~ poss_glance(.x))) %>%
  unnest(mod01)

# A tibble: 4 x 17
    cyl         data model1  model2 mod01 r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value    df
  <dbl> <list<tibbl> <list>  <list> <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     2      [5 x 2] <dbl [~ <dbl ~    NA   NA             NA     NA      NA      NA          NA
2     4     [11 x 2] <lm>    <lm>      NA    0.648          0.609  2.82   16.6     0.00278     1
3     6      [7 x 2] <lm>    <dbl ~    NA    0.0106        -0.187  1.58    0.0537  0.826       1
4     8     [14 x 2] <lm>    <lm>      NA    0.270          0.209  2.28    4.44    0.0568      1
# ... with 6 more variables: logLik <dbl>, AIC <dbl>, BIC <dbl>, deviance <dbl>,
#   df.residual <int>, nobs <int>
```

Or even we could use `safely` in place of `possibly` so that our function returns an enhanced output in this case `NA_real_`:

```
safe_glance <- safely(glance, otherwise = NA_real_)

Model_fits %>%
  mutate(mod01 = map(model1, ~ safe_glance(.x)))
```

Comment: Thanks. `purrr::possibly()` is similar to `tryCatch()` with a simpler syntax. But it didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand the issue now. Selecting this as the solution because doing `is.na()` on a model object throws a warning.

Comment: Glad it helped and I myself learned about it just now. I suggest you also read the documentation, it was quite helpful in this case as I realized it never wraps the function while applying on data but writes a custom to wrap the function before being applied. About the choice of answer it's down to you and I don't mind being/not being chosen at all. It has been a very good question. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can just check if the value is `NA` in a wrapper function that you pass to `map`.

```
Model_fits %>% 
   mutate(summary_res = map(model1, function(x) if (length(x) == 1 && is.na(x)) NA_real_ else  broom::glance(x)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am wondering why `possibly()` didn't work.